# Angular: How to handle "SafeValue must use [property]=binding:" error with (click) event?

Tags: angular

I am trying to create Facebook share button,

**Component,**

```
  ngOnInit() {
        this.WebURL = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.data.url);
        this.facebookURL = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+this.WebURL);
  }    

  socialTab(link){
    window.open(
        link,
        '_blank' 
    );   
  }
```

**HTML,**

```
<md-menu #socialButton="mdMenu" >
    <button md-menu-item (click)="socialTab(facebookURL)">
        <img src="app/assets/images/facebook.png"/>
    </button>
</md-menu>
```

But this code trigger following error,

> SafeValue must use [property]=binding:

**And I tried this way also, but it wasn't success and given above error**

**Component,**

```
  ngOnInit() {
        this.WebURL = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.data.url);
        this.facebookURL = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+this.WebURL);
  }    

  socialTab(link){
      if(link == 'fb'){
        window.open(
            this.facebookURL,
            '_blank' 
        );  
      }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<md-menu #socialButton="mdMenu" >
    <button md-menu-item (click)="socialTab('fb')">
        <img src="app/assets/images/facebook.png"/>
    </button>
</md-menu>
```

Someone please advise me to solve this issue. Thank You.

Comment: you need to use the property binding for the image's src attribute as such:  [src]=this.WebURL

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in using `DomSanitizer` for

```
  window.open(
        this.facebookURL,
        '_blank' 
    );
```

it is only required for adding HTML or styles to the DOM by Angular.

The error is probably because of

```
(click)="socialTab(facebookURL)"
```

which passes the sanitized value around instead of adding it to the DOM using

```
<div [innerHTML]="someSanitizedValue"
```

Sanitization wraps the value in a different type, so that Angular can check later if it's sanitized (explicitely declared safe) before it actually adds it to the DOM.

`window.open(` is not related to Angular in any way and it also takes a string not a `SafeUrl` or similar.